# Why was the swap operator proposal shot down?

Tags: c++, swap, language-design

[Proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3746.pdf)

I read this a while ago and it sounds like an incredible idea. But, obviously, it hasn't made it into C++14, and it doesn't even seem to be coming to C++17. What's the reasoning?

Comment: The isocpp.org forum is the right place to ask questions to committee members. I can only find traces of a discussion for N3553 in Bristol, basically saying that adding yet another way to do a swap won't fix the old swap.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reasoning behind a committee's decision, which should be addressed to that committee's forums where it is more appropriate.

Comment: @KenWhite nonsense. StackOverflow has never been about RTFM, and if there's a public record of the decision then there's no reason a summary couldn't be produced here.

Comment: @Mark: I didn't say RTFM anywhere in my comment (nor did I imply any such *nonsense*), and if there's a public record at the committee's site there's absolutely no reason for it to be produced here.

Comment: @KenWhite I felt your comment was analogous to saying RTFM - if the answer exists in a manual, why should it also be on StackOverflow? Having an official place to get an answer has *never* been a reason to avoid duplicating it here, although the best answers always link to their sources.

Comment: @Mark: In this case, however, it's not an actual programming question; it's a question about the reasoning behind the committee's decision. Questions asking why a third party made a decision are typically off topic here, and I don't see this one as an exception.

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't really think it'd be a problem but now that I know it is, it won't be happening again. I've added an actual programming question now to make up for it!

Comment: You should ask a separate question instead of editing this one into a completely new one, but the answer is that sometimes memberwise swap won't work; for example, suppose you have `struct A { int a; int *p_a; /* member functions omitted */ };` where the invariant is `p_a == &a`, then you'd better not swap `p_a` when swapping two `A`s.

Comment: This is not a practical question. Knowing why a proposal was rejected won't affect the way you write programs. You have to deal with the committee decision, even if the reason is "Because we don't like you."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For background, the paper you've linked to proposes adding `operator:=:` to the language to accomplish what the following does today

```
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

Instead you'd write,

```
a :=: b;
```

This is tracked by [EWG issue 54](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/ewg/issue54) and was rejected as *not a defect* because the technique of using unqualified calls to `swap` will persist despite the new operator because without it, all user defined `swap` functions will be rendered useless. Moreover, adding the operator does not remove the need for having to rely on ADL to find the type specific `swap` implementation, if one exists.

Quoting Bjarne from the link above:

> But `swap()` isn't going away because of backward compatibility, so now we'll have `swap()` and `operator:=:`. "Probably a good idea if we had a time machine". Introducing a new operator, it has to be really central and helpful. If it got us out of our swap problem it might be good enough, but it isn't. Libraries aren't going to stop calling swap and if they did then all the specialized swap functions people have written wouldn't get invoked. Problems are real, but the benefits it would have (i.e. what problem it would actually solve) aren't sufficiently explained. Too likely that `swap` and `:=:` would coexist indefinitely and that all the problems of swap would persist.
>
> General agreement that this is a real problem but that it's not clear why this would solve them. We will not proceed with this.
>
> No recommendation to move forward, considered NAD.